# What to do if I find an error in a third party declaration file?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

What can I do if I find an error in a declaration file from an external NPM library?

What if the declaration file is in the NPM package itself?
What if it's from DefinitelyTyped?

Can I somehow copy and paste the file, make my adjustments, and have typescript read from my version of the file?

Of course, I don't want to directly edit node_modules because the adjustments wouldn't be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

I had to put my file in a folder that is included in the `paths` prop of my `tsconfig.json` *before* `"node_modules/*"`
In my case it ended up like this:

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["src/types/*", "node_modules/*"]
}
```

My custom declaration files are in src/types